# Making Socket and rest to work together using nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, express, socket.io

Currently I am using "Socket.io" package in my node application and I want to access IO instance in my rest calls.

Following is code I had tried.

index.js

```
const app = express();
const newServer = require('http').Server(app);
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(newServer);

app.use("/restApiCall", require("./apis"));

newServer.listen(8002, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening to port 8002`);
});
```

apis.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router(); 
const SubmoduleController = require("./controllers/subModule.js");

router.route('/abc').post(SubmoduleController.updateAbc);
```

subModule.js

```
module.exports = {
   updateAbc: async function (req, res, next) {
      /*** Here i want access my socket IO instance and emit message to UI
   }
}
```

How do I achieve this. Since IO instance is part of index.js and rest api are written in different files. How do I Pass instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both socket.io and express server (for REST API), you should listen on 2 different port.